# Apply css styles to option tag in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Consider the html below.

```
<select text="Choose any one">
    <option>Germany</option>
    <option>France</option>
    <option>US</option>
    <option>UK</option>
    <option>India</option>
</select>
```

I want to give 20px height for each dropdown row. So the following css is applied.

```
option{
    height:20px;
}
```

This is working perfectly in firefox. But not in chrome. Can anyone suggest a solution for this? Also tried to give height for odd and even rows. But not working in chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot edit option tags. Consider using li tags for better control, though it might mean more coding

Comment: Or just leave it alone and let the browser do the styling. Users will be familiar with how their browser's form elements are styled. Why mess with their heads?